# How to use the spread option for a tcolorbox together with the crop package?

Tags: tcolorbox, geometry, crop

When I use a spreading tcolorbox together with the geometry and crop packages, tcolorbox ignores the page offsets given by crop. This does not happen with non-spreading tcolorboxes as shown in my MWE. How can I get all tcolorboxes to respect these offsets?

```
\documentclass[%
    a5paper,
    portrait]{report}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4,center]{crop}
\crop
\geometry{%
        centering,
        top=20mm, 
        bottom=20mm,
        inner=30mm,
        outer=20mm}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\blindtext
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    colupper=black,
    title hidden]
    \blindtext
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    colupper=black,
    spread,
    title hidden]
    \blindtext
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Because the `crop` packages increases the margins and shifts the origin of the page, you need to manually set the spread for the `tcolorbox`.

The height and width of the page are stored in `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth` while the height and width of the stock (i.e. the page plus the bleed) are stored in `\stockheight` and `\stockwidth` You can use these values to calculate how much the spread should be reduced from the margins of the stock (namely exactly half the difference of `\stockheight` and `\paperheight` and of `\stockwidth` and `\paperwidth` respectively).

Note that you cannot use `spread upwards` and `spread downwards` because these options will also set the width of the box which won't work here.

```
\documentclass[%
    a5paper,
    portrait]{report}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4,center]{crop}
\crop
\geometry{%
        centering,
        top=20mm, 
        bottom=20mm,
        inner=30mm,
        outer=20mm}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\blindtext
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    colupper=black,
    title hidden]
    \blindtext
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    colupper=black,
    move upwards={-0.5\stockheight+0.5\paperheight},
    fill downwards={0.5\stockheight-0.5\paperheight},
    spread inwards={0.5\stockwidth-0.5\paperwidth},
    spread outwards={-0.5\stockwidth+0.5\paperwidth},
    title hidden]
    \blindtext
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 0.5 seems to work perfectly in all standard paper sizes.

Comment: Of course, the width of the bleed (the additional margin added by `crop`) it exactly half the width of `\stockwidth` minus half the width of `\paperwidth` and the same is true for the height.